# Google Map <iframe> unable to load Chrome version30.0.1599

Tags: html, google-maps, google-chrome

I have  tag used to load the google map in my web site. All browser load the google map Successfully , Except google chrome  Version 30.0.1599.69 .  how to fix this issue in Google chrome 30.0.1599.69 ? give me suggestion .

Sample code:

Comment: below code not working <iframe width="940" height="400" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=&amp;layer=c&amp;sll=12.985341,77.580991&amp;cid=7397498743411235075&amp;panoid=VKViTFSBVu8AAAQJODP41A&amp;cbp=13,21.19,,0,-0.1&amp;gl=US&amp;hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=12.985341,77.580991&amp;spn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;t=m&amp;cbll=12.98536,77.580997&amp;source=embed&amp;output=svembed"></iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a Google trusted photographer and this issue is a big problem for my clients.

before the issue was solved, you could use the maps api. I did this little tool : http://visitevirtuelle.odoxo.fr/bug-de-chrome-30-et-des-iframe-de-google-maps/ to replace the google iframe by a modified one, it works for Streetview and business photo (and really simple maps).

It could help.